# going back an activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I can go to my SoundActivity class from my mainActivity, which is a menu. However when i click the device back button it does not go back to my mainActivity instead it just closes the app. I have put finish() at the end but that hasn't seemed to work. I have also tried the super.backPressed() and that hasn't worked either.
This is the code for the sound class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

 public class SoundActivity extends Activity
    {
MediaPlayer ourSong;

private SeekBar volumeSeekbar = null;
private ToggleButton muteButton = null;
private AudioManager audioManager = null;

private AudioManager mAm;
private boolean mIsMute;
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    setContentView(R.layout.soundmenu);
    initControls();


    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(SoundActivity.this, R.raw.beat2);
    ourSong.start();

}



private void initControls()
{
    try
    {
        volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sbVolumeBar);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));   



        volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
            {
            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
            {
            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        progress, 0);
            }
        });

        muteButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        muteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(muteButton.isChecked())
            {
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                  am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
            }
            else
            {
                AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                  am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
            }
        }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();

    }
}
```

If anyone could help me i would be really grateful. Confused at the moment

ok heres the mainActivity that starts sound activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PinballShooterActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MediaPlayer ourSong;

private ToggleButton muteButton = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(PinballShooterActivity.this, R.raw.beat2);
    ourSong.start();

    Button soundBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sound); 
    soundBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



    public void onClick(View v) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
        startActivity(new Intent(PinballShooterActivity.this, SoundActivity.class));         
        }     
    });  

    Button highScrBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.highscores); 
    highScrBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



    public void onClick(View v) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
        startActivity(new Intent(PinballShooterActivity.this, HighScoreActivity.class));         
        }     
    });

    Button gameBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startgame); 
    gameBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


         public void onClick(View v) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub             
        startActivity(new Intent(PinballShooterActivity.this, GameActivity.class));         
        }     
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
    }
}
```

and here is the android manifest

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity 
            android:name=".SoundActivity" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".HighScoreActivity" />
        <activity 
            android:name=".GameActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.pinball.shooter.GAMEACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PinballShooterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action           android:name="com.pinball.shooter.faiz.PINBALLSHOOTERACTIVITY"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: It likely has less to do with your soundActivity class and more to do with how SoundActivity was started.  Show us MainActivity and possibly your manifest and we can probably help better :)

Comment: Take the finish(); out of onPause, that's what your activity is doing anyway .. pauseing

Comment: tried still did not work

Comment: @akki You probably have the same mistake in MainActivity. Remove `finish()` from MainActivity's `onPause()`.

Comment: @paul thank you it worked, just had to take finsh() out of onPause().

Comment: @akkki Glad to hear it! I've posted my comment as an answer so that you can mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in my comment above, the problem lies not in SoundActivity, but in MainActivity: when MainActivity is paused after launching SoundActivity, it finishes due to `finish()` in `onPause()`:

```
public class PinballShooterActivity extends Activity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        ourSong.release();
        finish();
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Simply remove `finish()` and your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you this method worked but the problem i get now is that when i go back to the mainActivity the sound stops playing. I tried to do onResume() with ourSong.reset() but it did not work

Comment: When you press back, that activity is cleaned up by Android. A simple solution would be managing playback of your audio through the Application class instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSong.release();
    finish();
    }
}
```

You have finish() in your onPause(). Everytime your SoundActivity is called, MainActivity goes to the background and its onPause() is called, which in turn calls your finish() and finishes the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can move anywhere in your application by pressing the phone back button. you just have to use the onBackPressed() method and use some lines of code  as i show u below

```
public void onBackPressed() {

     Intent start = new Intent(Current activity.this,on which activity you want to move .class);
        startActivity(start);
        finishActivity(0);
        }
```